# How to remove cookies from specific pages in joomla 3?

Tags: php, cookies, joomla, menu, joomla3.0

I want to remove all active cookies from a menu item of my joomla site.

This is what I have tried so far. But its not working. Please advice.

```
    $menu = &JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->id ;
if (($menu ==160 )OR ($menu ==162)){
     setcookie("4fac4a40aea2f01167c39f90e7f86b74", '', time()-1000);
    setcookie("3ba91267df8ad1212d2c1e507c7cf988", '', time()-1000);
}
    ?>
```

I want to delete two cookies if a active menu id is 160 or 162 (not menu item id).

Comment: What happens? And where are you getting the cookie name?

Comment: @Elin : i print cookies "print_r($_COOKIE);" and get the results from there . but using above command cookies are not removing.

Comment: You should use the Joomla API. Are you using a cookie viewer browser plugin? How do you know those are the cookies you actually want to change? I can't stay but this is an example of how to set a cookie to destroy it: `// Destroy the cookie
  $this->app->input->cookie->set($cookieName, false, time() - 42000, $this->app->get('cookie_path', '/'), $this->app->get('cookie_domain'));`

Comment: @Elin : if an admin login with system , will it remove there cookies as well ? i want to remove all cookies except admin user cookie . Please advice

Comment: That will remove whatever you name. I think you need to be more clear about what you mean by "all" cookies.

Comment: @Elin : how to remove a httponly cookie from joomla ? please advice

Comment: You don't remove cookies from Joomla, you remove them from the user's browser. YCCou use code like what I showed you, but you must know the name of the cookie you want to remove.